# Installing GUI on Arch

Tags: linux, arch-linux, desktop-environment

So I've installed and configured everything on my Arch (VMware) except for graphics. I want it to be like I boot to a terminal, then I press X (it is Xorg, right?) and GUI pops out. How can I install it, which drivers should I choose? Got nVidia GeForce 820M

I know about its great wiki and I got through many its pages, Xorg, GNOME (which I want to install), but I did not quite find an answer how to install xorg + gnome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Installation

`pacman -S extra/gnome` installs **a lot** of things, including Xord and GDM.  `extra/gnome` is a group of packages which you can select or deselect in `pacman`.  But for a typical gnome install you're very likely to want all of them.

From there you can simply enable GDM to run on boot with:

```
systemctl enable gdm.service
```

The you can either reboot or use:

```
systemctl start gdm.service
```

To start the display manager right there.

---

#### Get into the display from tty

To start gnome from the command line, you want the GDM service to be disabled.

```
systemctl disable gdm.service
```

And you need two files in your home directory `.xsession` and `.xinitrc`.  To make things simpler it is wise to use a `.xsession` that calls `.xinitrc`.  For example

`.xsession`

```
#!/bin/sh

if test -r "$HOME/.xinitrc"
then
    source "$HOME/.xinitrc"
fi
```

And then you can place whatever you need in `.xinitrc`

`.xinitrc`

```
# Sometimes D-BUS stuff is placed here by packages, pick it up
if test -d /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc.d
then
    for f in /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc.d/*
    do
        [ -x "$f" ] && source "$f"
    done
    unset f
fi

# random config
setxkbmap us
xrdb .Xresources
export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin

# get into gnome
exec gnome-session
```

Now, this is important, both files must be executable.

```
chmod 755 .xsession .xinitrc
```

And you can perform `startx` from the tty to start Xorg and then Gnome.

---

#### Nvidia

Arch has several drivers available from the main repositories.

- `extra/nvidia` has the latest ones (latest ones in the official repos, AUR will have slightly never ones).
- `extra/nvidia-304xx`/`extra/nvidia-304xx` are the ones for older cards.

I'm not following NVIDIA's name conventions, you will need to go through the [arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/NVIDIA) and [nouveau conventions](https://nouveau.freedesktop.org/wiki/CodeNames/) to find which one has a chance to work.

But really, something of the lines of:

```
lspci -k | grep VGA
```

Will also give you a better idea of the name of your card.

---

Notes:

- Xorg is a display server, it deals with creating the display (or several displays).
- GDM is a display manger, it deals with authentication and communication between the display server and the window manager.
- Gnome is a window manager (actually it is other things as well but for our purposes it fill the window manager application stack), it provides the user with tools to interact with the display and applications with the API for windows (through GTK).

References:

- [Arch wiki on NVIDIA](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/NVIDIA)

Comment: Thanks for a constructive answer! So how can I do the thing with booting into a text cmd line?

Comment: @Frynio - forgot about that, sorry.  Now updated.  As for NVIDIA, it is a little tricky.  I have no idea which series that card is from, but it is from 2014 so it should probably go with plain `extra/nvidia` (as a wild guess based on how quickly the drivers are released).

Comment: lspci gives me VMware card actually

Comment: @Frynio - The bright side is that the VMware card certainly works out of the box.  The bad side is that it (probably) will not allow hardware acceleration.  [According to NVIDIA](http://www.nvidia.com/object/dedicated-gpus.html) it is possible to access the GPU from inside a VM with some extra stuff (it even has a link to VMware in there) but I certainly never attempted such thing.